# Combining columns, while ignoring duplicates and NAs

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe as follows and I would like to combine two columns, namely `Var1` and `Var2`. I want the combined column (`Var3`) to contain no duplicates of `<alpha><digit>`. i.e. if `Var1 == A1` and `Var2 == A1`, hence `Var3 == A1` but not `Var3 == A1-A1` or if `Var1 == A4-E9` and `Var2 == A4`, hence `Var3 == A4-E9` but not `Var3 == A4-E9-A4`

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 
"id  Var1    Var2
A   A1       A1
B   F2       A2
C   NA       A3
D   A4-E9    A4
E   E5       A5
F   NA       NA
G   B2-R4    A3-B2
H   B3-B4    E1-G5", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The following is my code. I would like to improve on its readability as well as get rid of the `NA` that is present in row 3's entry for `Var3`, i.e `A3-NA`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Var3 = paste(Var1, Var2, sep = "-"))  %>%
  separate_rows(Var3, sep = "-") %>%
  group_by(id, Var3) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(Var3 = paste(unlist(Var3[!is.na(Var3)]), collapse = "-")) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup
```

Here's my desired output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
     id  Var1  Var2        Var3
  <chr> <chr> <chr>       <chr>
1     A    A1    A1          A1
2     B    F2    A2       A2-F2
3     C  <NA>    A3          A3
4     D A4-E9    A4       A4-E9
5     E    E5    A5       A5-E5
6     F  <NA>  <NA>        <NA>
7     G B2-R4 A3-B2    A3-B2-R4
8     H B3-B4 E1-G5 B3-B4-E1-G5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if 'df1' is the output, then we remove the 'NA' that follows a `-` with `sub`

```
df1 %>% 
    mutate(Var3 = sub("-NA", "", Var3))
# A tibble: 8 x 4
#     id  Var1  Var2        Var3
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>       <chr>
#1     A    A1    A1          A1
#2     B    F2    A2       A2-F2
#3     C  <NA>    A3          A3
#4     D A4-E9    A4       A4-E9
#5     E    E5    A5       A5-E5
#6     F  <NA>  <NA>          NA
#7     G B2-R4 A3-B2    A3-B2-R4
#8     H B3-B4 E1-G5 B3-B4-E1-G5
```

---

We can also do this slightly differently with `tidyverse` by `gather` into 'long' format, then split the 'value' column using `separate_rows`, grouped by 'id', `summarise` the 'Var3' column by `paste`ing the `sort`ed `unique` elements of 'Var3' and `left_join` with the original dataset 'df'

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df, key, value, -id) %>%
       separate_rows(value)  %>%
       group_by(id) %>% 
       summarise(Var3 = paste(sort(unique(value)), collapse='-')) %>% 
       mutate(Var3 = replace(Var3, Var3=='', NA)) %>% 
       left_join(df, .)
#   id  Var1  Var2        Var3
#1  A    A1    A1          A1
#2  B    F2    A2       A2-F2
#3  C  <NA>    A3          A3
#4  D A4-E9    A4       A4-E9
#5  E    E5    A5       A5-E5
#6  F  <NA>  <NA>        <NA>
#7  G B2-R4 A3-B2    A3-B2-R4
#8  H B3-B4 E1-G5 B3-B4-E1-G5
```

NOTE: The `%>%` makes even a simple code to appear in multiple lines, but if required, we can put all those statements in a single line and term as `one-liner`

---

Here is a one-liner

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Var3 := paste(sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(unlist(.SD),"-")))), collapse="-"), id]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do it in one line

```
df$Var3 = lapply(strsplit(paste(df$Var1, df$Var2, sep = "-"),"-"),
                 function(x)paste(unique(x)[unique(x)!="NA"],collapse="-"))
```

Output:

```
  id  Var1  Var2        Var3
1  A    A1    A1          A1
2  B    F2    A2       F2-A2
3  C  <NA>    A3          A3
4  D A4-E9    A4       A4-E9
5  E    E5    A5       E5-A5
6  F  <NA>  <NA>            
7  G B2-R4 A3-B2    B2-R4-A3
8  H B3-B4 E1-G5 B3-B4-E1-G5
```

- The first part in the lapply function is similar to your first call with dplyr. First the columns are concatenated, and then we split them again.
- The function within lapply removes all NA's, and then collapses the string again.

Hope this helps!

> EDIT: Speed comparison for fun!
>
> - 262,144 rows
>
> Average runtimes:
>
> - Florian: 3.97 seconds
> - Sotos: 2.46 seconds
> - Akrun: **1.34 seconds**
> - Adamm: >120 seconds

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 
                   "id  Var1    Var2
A   A1       A1
B   F2       A2
C   NA       A3
D   A4-E9    A4
E   E5       A5
F   NA       NA
G   B2-R4    A3-B2
H   B3-B4    E1-G5", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for(i in 1:15)
{
  df = rbind(df,df)
}

library(microbenchmark)

# Florian's method
microbenchmark(
lapply(strsplit(paste(df$Var1, df$Var2, sep = "-"),"-"),
                 function(x)paste(unique(x)[unique(x)!="NA"],collapse="-")),times=5)

# Sotos'method
microbenchmark(
gsub('NA-|-NA', '', vapply(strsplit(do.call(paste, df[-1]), " |-"), function(i) paste(unique(i), collapse = "-"), character(1L))), times=5)

# akrun method
library(data.table)
microbenchmark(
setDT(df)[, Var3 := paste(sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(unlist(.SD),"-")))), collapse="-"), id], times=5)

# Adamm method
microbenchmark(
sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) ifelse(df[i,2]!=df[i,3] & !is.na(df[i,2]) & !is.na(df[i,3]), paste(df[i,2], df[i,3], sep="-"), ifelse(!is.na(df[i,3]), df[i,3], df[i,2]))), times=5)
```

Comment: This might be a bit more efficient `gsub('NA-|-NA', '', vapply(strsplit(do.call(paste, df[-1]), " |-"), function(i) 
                                         paste(unique(i), collapse = "-"), character(1L)))`

Answer (score 2):

If you want complex solution; long one-liner, nested `ifelse()`.

```
df$Var3 <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) ifelse(df[i,2]!=df[i,3] & !is.na(df[i,2]) & !is.na(df[i,3]), paste(df[i,2], df[i,3], sep="-"), ifelse(!is.na(df[i,3]), df[i,3], df[i,2])))

> df
  id  Var1  Var2        Var3
1  A    A1    A1          A1
2  B    F2    A2       F2-A2
3  C  <NA>    A3          A3
4  D A4-E9    A4    A4-E9-A4
5  E    E5    A5       E5-A5
6  F  <NA>  <NA>        <NA>
7  G B2-R4 A3-B2 B2-R4-A3-B2
8  H B3-B4 E1-G5 B3-B4-E1-G5
```

In case of efficiency I made a small experiment and I measured time of each proposed solution, here are the results:

First of all I need more rows:

```
n <- 10000                       
df <- do.call("rbind", replicate(n, df, simplify = FALSE))
```

**Akrun solution 1 with `tidyverse`**

```
Time difference of 1.452809 secs
```

**Akrun solution 2 with `data.table`**

```
Time difference of 0.4530261 secs
```

**Florian Maas solution with `lapply`**

```
Time difference of 1.812106 secs
```

**My solution with `sapply`**

```
Time difference of 2.289345 mins
```

**Sotos solution**

```
Time difference of 1.515296 secs
```